# How to integrate apache ignite with spark dataframe and how to apply index on the spark dataframe?

Tags: ignite

I just want to perform join on two spark dataframe using apache ignite indexes.Please guide me how to do this step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Ignite's documentation has a great instruction for this: https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/ignite-data-frame